# python import class in module throws ImportError

Tags: python, class, import, module, spyder

Sorry if this question seems very simple, i am quite experienced in java but absolutely not in python, and the way importations works in python is still quite a mistery to me. 

 The problem being that from what i have collected from the internet, i feel like I have done everything that is necessary for my script to import a module inside a folder.

my project looks like this

```
/omme
    start.py
    /foo
        __init__.py   #is empty
        bar.py        #has a class named BarClass
```

start.py only has this

```
from foo.bar import BarClass

b = BarClass()
```

when i run this script in the spyder IDE i get this

```
runfile('/home/nathan/Documents/workspace/omme/start.py', wdir='/home/nathan/Documents/workspace/omme')
Reloaded modules: foo.bar
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-38-c3b9ba6593fb>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/nathan/Documents/workspace/omme/start.py', wdir='/home/nathan/Documents/workspace/omme')

  File "/home/nathan/.anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/home/nathan/.anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/nathan/Documents/workspace/omme/start.py", line 1, in <module>
    from foo.bar import BarClass

ImportError: cannot import name 'BarClass'
```

and then even weirder, if I replace  `foo.bar`  by  `test.bar`  it throws a ModuleNotFoundException (I suspect some ide shenanigans).

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you for your time, sincerly nathan.

Comment: Try `import foo.bar` followed by `print(foo.bar)` and `print(dir(foo.bar))`, to see what you actually imported.

Comment: @zvone it gives me respectively :`<module 'foo.bar' from '/home/nathan/Documents/workspace/omme/foo/bar.py'>` and `Reloaded modules: foo.bar
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'barClass']`

Comment: It looks like your class is named `barClass` instead of `BarClass`.

Comment: @zvone you were right, I feel embarassed for such a foolish mistake ... thank you for patience. funnily enough if `foo.bar` is replace with `test.bar` it stoppes working. But anyway, i'll just avoid making folder named test. on another note : do you thin that I should remove this question as the answer is so blatantly common ?

Comment: Yes, I think you should remove the question :) Anyway, the `test` problem may be something more interesting, but for that also try `import test; print(test)` - you probably have some other `test` module laying around

Comment: @vzone, I can't remove it because "others have invested time and efforts into answering it". And yes, once again, you were right, i have another 'test' lib hidden in `/home/nathan/.anaconda3/lib/python3.6/test/__init__.py`, well at least now, I know how to check what module I'm actually loading thanks to you ^^. I'll change my answer in order to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for @zvone, I now know my mistake : i just mispelled the name of the class... sorry for your time.

As I can't remove the question, I'll tell you the simple trick @vzone told me to solve the two problems i had:

```
import lib
print (lib)
```

let you check from where the lib is located, as you may be loading a similarly named lib from somewhere else. which happened to me with my `test.bar` 
furthermore using

```
import lib
print (dir( lib))
```

gives you a pretty neat look on what is in your classes which makes it easier to debug.

Thank the lad, he did it all in the comments.